# jQuery get table header text for each td in table row

Tags: jquery, html-table

As you can see in the following fiddle, I am dynamically creating a table with multiple tr's being used for the column headers.  I need to get the text that is in the header for for each td in the selected row.

http://jsfiddle.net/michaela_elise/Gj6L5/

Each of the valid header th's has a class "isHeader" in order to be distinguished from the other th's.

This is the function that gets called when a valid td gets clicked:

```
function serializeAny($trow)
    {
        var ret = [];
        $.each( $trow.children(), function() {  
            var pos = $(this).index();
            var header = $allCells.filter(":nth-child(" + (pos+1) + ")").hasClass("isHeader");
            alert(header.text());
            ret.push( encodeURIComponent( header.text() ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( $(this).text() ) );
        });

        return ret.join("&").replace(/%20/g, "+");
    }
```

The 'var header' is supposed to get the header that for that column that has the class 'isHeader'.

I am very new to this and am just not sure how to traverse to it.

So for example if I click in the row labeled '1234', I would like the function to return 'Input, blahs, Tag, what, who, where, "SKIP THIS COLUMN (No isHeader class), IH, A, Email, .....'.

Comment: `hasClass` returns a boolean value... so `header.text()` will throw an error

Comment: you need `$allCells.filter(":nth-child(" + (pos+1) + ").isHeader")`

Comment: who is calling `serializeAny`?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/M5gyh/1/

Comment: serializeAny() is being called in the event handler function which I did not post because it was not working with this stripped down fiddle.  It is called when a valid td gets clicked.  The variable &trow is coming from the populateVars function that gets called when a valid td is moused over and/or clicked.

Comment: a more cleaner way is http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/M5gyh/2/

Comment: can you check the updated versions?

Comment: That is really close! it doesn't get the first first 6 headers though.

Comment: I think you are mixing it up... `isHeader` & `isheader`

Comment: can you fix the case in the class name and try

Comment: try to mark the solutions which solved your problem as accepted

Answer (score 1):

You are using `isHeader` and `isheader` in your code, fix to any one of them and use it in your class selector below

```
function serializeAny($trow) {
    console.log('serializeAny');
    var $headers = $('#processOutput, #heads');
    var ret = $trow.children().map(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            pos = $this.index();
        var header = $headers.find("th:nth-child(" + (pos + 1) + ").isHeader");
        return header.length ? encodeURIComponent(header.text()) + "=" + encodeURIComponent($this.text()) : undefined
    }).get();

    return ret.join("&").replace(/%20/g, "+");
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/M5gyh/)

Answer (score 0):

I would give this a try:

```
var header = $('#heads').children(':eq('+$(this).index()+')');
```

Comment: Nice, this gets the first 6 but not the last ones.  I think maybe if I use a combination of this answer and Arun P Johny's answer, I will be able to get them all